# A "paradox" involving the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I have the following question regarding the dominated convergence theorem. I was trying to apply it, but then got a contradiction that I could not resolve. Let $\zeta := |.|$ be the counting measure:

We can calculate the geometric series ($n \geq 1$)$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{k} = \frac{1}{1 - (n+1)^{-1}} = \frac{n+1}{n}$$

The functions $f_{n}(k) := \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^k $ are measurable functions on the measure space $(\mathbb{N},\mathcal{P(\mathbb{N})}, \zeta)$. Obviously, for $n \to \infty$,they converge pointwise to the zero function $f_{0}(k) := 0$. We also have $$\int_{\mathbb{N}} | f_{n}(k)| d\zeta(k) \leq \int_{\mathbb{N}} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} d\zeta(k) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k} = 2 $$

so we have an integrable dominating function for the sequence $f_{n}$. By the dominated convergence theorem, we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{N}} f_{n}(k) d\zeta(k) = \int_{\mathbb{N}}f_0 (k) d\zeta(k) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{k} = 0$$

A contradiction to the formula above that tells us that the limit is equal to 1. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What happens when $k=0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions $(f_n(k))_{k=0}^\infty$ do not converge to $0$, since $f_n(0) = 1$ for all $k$. This is in agreement with your original result.

Comment: Thanks :) I feel a little stupid now.

Comment: Don't, it's a mistake anyone can make and it's good to make sure you understand the fundamental theorems.